# Why am I getting timeout error in Django Channels?

Tags: python, django, websocket, pytest, django-channels

I have recently started learning Django Channels and found this very nice and detailed project: [Real-Time Taxi App With Django Channels and React](https://coursehunters.online/t/testdriven-io-developing-a-real-time-taxi-app-with-django-channels-and-react-pt-1/3301). However, this project uses Django Channels v2.3.1 and I have v3.0.3 so I made the changes to make it work the latest version. The code below is supposed to be working in the latest version but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

`test_websocket.py`

```
    import pytest
    from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
    from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
    from channels.testing import WebsocketCommunicator
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken
    
    from taxi.asgi import application
    
    TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer'
        }
    }
    
    
    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_user(username, password):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            password=password
        )
        access = AccessToken.for_user(user)
        return user, access
    
    
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    @pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
    class TestWebSocket:
        async def test_can_connect_to_server(self, settings):
            settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS = TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS
            _, access = await create_user('test.user@example.com', 'pAssw0rd')
            communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(application=application, path=f'/taxi/?token={access}')
            connected, _ = await communicator.connect()
            assert connected is True
            await communicator.disconnect()
    
        async def test_can_send_and_receive_messagges(self, settings):
            settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS = TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS
            communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(
                application=application,
                path='/taxi/'
            )
            connected, _ = await communicator.connect()
            message = {
                'type': 'echo.message',
                'data': 'This is a test message.'
            }
            await communicator.send_json_to(message)
            response = await communicator.receive_json_from()
            assert response == message
            await communicator.disconnect()
    
        async def test_can_send_and_receive_broadcast_messages(self, settings):
            settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS = TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS
            communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(
                application=application,
                path='/taxi/'
            )
            connected, _ = await communicator.connect()
            message = {
                'type': 'echo.message',
                'data': 'This is a test message.',
            }
            channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
            await channel_layer.group_send('test', message=message)
            response = await communicator.receive_json_from()
            assert response == message
            await communicator.disconnect()
    
        async def test_cannot_connect_to_socket(self, settings):
            settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS = TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS
            communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(
                application=application,
                path='/taxi/'
            )
            connected, _ = await communicator.connect()
            assert connected is False
            await communicator.disconnect()
```

`middleware.py`

```
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs
    
    from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
    from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
    from channels.middleware import BaseMiddleware
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
    from django.db import close_old_connections
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken
    
    User = get_user_model()
    
    
    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user(user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return AnonymousUser()
    
    
    class TokenAuthMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
        def __init__(self, app):
            self.app = app
    
        async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
            close_old_connections()
            query_string = parse_qs(scope['query_string'].decode())
            token = query_string.get('token')
            if not token:
                scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()
                return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
            scope['user'] = await get_user(AccessToken(token[0])['id'])
            return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
            # return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
    
    
    def TokenAuthMiddlewareStack(inner):
        return TokenAuthMiddleware(AuthMiddlewareStack(inner))
```

`The error`:

```
====================================================== FAILURES =======================================================
_____________________________ TestWebSocket.test_can_send_and_receive_broadcast_messages ______________________________

self = <channels.testing.websocket.WebsocketCommunicator object at 0x0000017CAA4B6AF0>, timeout = 1

    async def receive_output(self, timeout=1):
        """
        Receives a single message from the application, with optional timeout.
        """
        # Make sure there's not an exception to raise from the task
        if self.future.done():
            self.future.result()
        # Wait and receive the message
        try:
            async with async_timeout(timeout):
>               return await self.output_queue.get()

..\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\testing.py:74:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <Queue at 0x17caa4b62e0 maxsize=0 tasks=1>

    async def get(self):
        """Remove and return an item from the queue.

        If queue is empty, wait until an item is available.
        """
        while self.empty():
            getter = self._loop.create_future()
            self._getters.append(getter)
            try:
>               await getter
E               asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

E:\ProgramFiles\Python\lib\asyncio\queues.py:163: CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

self = <trips.tests.test_websocket.TestWebSocket object at 0x0000017CAA461FA0>
settings = <pytest_django.fixtures.SettingsWrapper object at 0x0000017CAA4CAEB0>

    async def test_can_send_and_receive_broadcast_messages(self, settings):
        settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS = TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS
        communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(
            application=application,
            path='/taxi/'
        )
        connected, _ = await communicator.connect()
        message = {
            'type': 'echo.message',
            'data': 'This is a test message.',
        }
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        await channel_layer.group_send('test', message=message)
>       response = await communicator.receive_json_from()

trips\tests\test_websocket.py:67:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\testing\websocket.py:93: in receive_json_from
    payload = await self.receive_from(timeout)
..\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\testing\websocket.py:72: in receive_from
    response = await self.receive_output(timeout)
..\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\testing.py:85: in receive_output
    raise e
..\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\testing.py:74: in receive_output
    return await self.output_queue.get()
..\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\timeout.py:66: in __aexit__
    self._do_exit(exc_type)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <asgiref.timeout.timeout object at 0x0000017CAA4B6310>, exc_type = <class 'asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError'>

    def _do_exit(self, exc_type: Type[BaseException]) -> None:
        if exc_type is asyncio.CancelledError and self._cancelled:
            self._cancel_handler = None
            self._task = None
>           raise asyncio.TimeoutError
E           asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

..\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\timeout.py:103: TimeoutError
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
FAILED trips/tests/test_websocket.py::TestWebSocket::test_can_send_and_receive_broadcast_messages - asyncio.exception...
============================================= 1 failed, 7 passed in 2.58s =============================================
```

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: The repo linked in the article was updated since the time you've asked the question: https://github.com/testdrivenio/taxi-react-app/commits/master have you seen it? Was it of any help?

Comment: Is `communicator.connect()` returning actually true?